# Injecting client proxy in JSF Bean

Tags: spring, jsf, jax-ws

In my project, Web services are implemented using JAX WS - RI.

I want to call the web service methods from the JSF managed beans.

I mean to say I require the spring injection of client proxy in the managed bean.

For CXF i have read that we can use jaxws:client tag in the spring application context xml.

But for JAXWS RI I have no idea.

Any idea how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to include the following preamble at the top of your Spring XML configuration file

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet
http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd"
```

and use the WebServiceServlet(WSS) tags.

More Info: [link](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/)